Deleting the comma before the "and" before the final author in a list of authors
I have the following code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  sorting=nty,
  citestyle=authoryear,
      backend=biber,
     bibstyle=authoryear,
   autolang=hyphen,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\addbibresource{bibl.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{meilland2024continuous}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

@article{meilland2024continuous,
  title={Continuous reproduction of planktonic foraminifera in laboratory culture},
  author={Meilland, Julie and Siccha, Michael and Morard, Rapha{\"e}l and Kucera, Michal},
  journal={Journal of Eukaryotic Microbiology},
  pages={13022},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

The bib output looks like:

However, I don't want the bibliography format to look like this:
Meilland, Julie; Siccha, Michael; Morard, Rapha ̈el, and Kucera, Michal (2024). Continuous reproduction of planktonic foraminifera in laboratory culture. In: Journal of Eukaryotic Microbiology, p. 13022.
but the comma before the and between Morard, Rapha ̈el and Kucera, Michal is deleted.
It should look like this:
Meilland, Julie; Siccha, Michael; Morard, Rapha ̈el and Kucera, Michal (2024). Continuous reproduction of planktonic foraminifera in laboratory culture. In: Journal of Eukaryotic Microbiology, p. 13022.

I've taken the liberty of changing "commuter" to "comma" in the title of your query. Feel free to revert.

You have two options:

Given some of the other instructions in your preamble, it would seem natural to add the instruction
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

to the preamble. Doing so would automatically suppress the Oxford comma -- as well as change the conjunction particle from "and" to "und" and change the sectioning header from "References" to "Literatur".

If loading babel with a suitable language choice is not indicated, I suggest you insert the instruction
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}}

toward the end of the preamble. (\AtBeginDocument{\let\finalandcomma\relax} works too.)


The following sample code implements the second option.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibl.bib}
@article{meilland2024continuous,
  title   = {Continuous reproduction of planktonic foraminifera in laboratory culture},
  author  = {Meilland, Julie and Siccha, Michael and Morard, Rapha{\"e}l and Kucera, Michal},
  journal = {Journal of Eukaryotic Microbiology},
  pages   = {13022},
  year    = {2024},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
      backend=biber,sorting=nty,
      citestyle=authoryear,
      bibstyle=authoryear,
      autolang=hyphen,
      maxbibnames=99,
      maxcitenames=2
  ]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} 
\usepackage{csquotes} % why no language option?
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}} % <-- new
\addbibresource{bibl.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{meilland2024continuous}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

